# Join multiple data frame in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following few data frames which have two columns each and have exactly the same number of rows. How do I join them so that I get a single data frame which has the two columns and all rows from both the data frames?

For example:

**DataFrame-1**

```
+--------------+-------------+
| colS         |  label      |
+--------------+-------------+
| sample_0_URI |  0          |
| sample_0_URI |  0          |
+--------------+-------------+
```

**DataFrame-2**

```
+--------------+-------------+
| colS         |  label      |
+--------------+-------------+
| sample_1_URI |  1          |
| sample_1_URI |  1          |
+--------------+-------------+
```

**DataFrame-3**

```
+--------------+-------------+
| col1         |  label      |
+--------------+-------------+
| sample_2_URI |  2          |
| sample_2_URI |  2          |
+--------------+-------------+
```

**DataFrame-4**

```
+--------------+-------------+
| col1         |  label      |
+--------------+-------------+
| sample_3_URI |  3          |
| sample_3_URI |  3          |
+--------------+-------------+
```

...

I want the result of the join to be:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| col1         |  label      |
+--------------+-------------+
| sample_0_URI |  0          |
| sample_0_URI |  0          |
| sample_1_URI |  1          |
| sample_1_URI |  1          |
| sample_2_URI |  2          |
| sample_2_URI |  2          |
| sample_3_URI |  3          |
| sample_3_URI |  3          |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Now, if I want to do one-hot encoding for **label** column, should it something like this:

```
oe = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="label",outputCol="one_hot_label")
df = oe.transform(df) # df is the joined dataframes <cols, label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `union`.

In this case, what I would do is put the dataframes in a `list` and use `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

dataframes = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]

result = reduce(lambda first, second: first.union(second), dataframes)
```

Comment: @WillSmith `OneHotEncoder` is deprecated in PySpark >= 2.3. Also, you should ask a new question, since the two are not even tangentially related.